# Кастомизация title в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Нужно к title добавлять номер страницы при пагинации.

Title выводится в header.php шаблона сайта:

```
<title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?></title>
```

Самый простой способ это сделать - проверить GET-параметры на наличие PAGEN, взять его оттуда и приклеить к title.

Невооруженным глазом видно, что это костыль.

Битрикс только изучаю, а задача нужна уже на вчера. Кто что подскажет по этому случаю? Может есть какие-то события? Как правильно это реализовать в рамках Битрикс?

```
<title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?><?php echo isset($_GET['PAGEN_1']) ? ('- ' . GetMessage("PAGINATION_TITLE") . ' ' . $_GET['PAGEN_1']) : ''?></title>
```

Comment: Костыль, тем более непонятно зачем нужный.  Вы все правильно поняли. Обработчики вообщем-то тут не нужны. Проверяйте Get и приклеивайте если есть PAGEN.

Comment: Это для сео, для избежания дублей. Сделал так.

Comment: Для избегания дублей правильно задавать канонический урл link rel=canonical, а не извращаться с заголовками.

Answer (score 3):

Привязывать к `$_GET['PAGEN_1']` не совсем правильно. В имени переменной зашит номер пагинации. Может получиться так, что вы добавите еще компонент перед этим и название будет уже `$_GET['PAGEN_2']`

Правильный вариант такой:

1. Рядом с шаблоном компонента `template.php` создать файл `result_modifier.php` и добавить туда код

```php
$cp = $this->__component;
if (is_object($cp))
{
    $cp->arResult["PAGE_NUMBER"]    = $arResult["NAV_RESULT"]->NavPageNomer;
    $cp->SetResultCacheKeys(["PAGE_NUMBER"]);
}
```

2. Создать там же `component_epilog.php` и добавить туда код:

```php
if ($arResult["PAGE_NUMBER"] > 1) {
    $APPLICATION->SetTitle($APPLICATION->GetTitle() . " - " . GetMessage("PAGINATION_TITLE") . " " . $arResult["PAGE_NUMBER"]);
}
```